# How can you pass a dynamic value to register in React Hook Form?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I'm using the React Hook Form library. The forms are dynamic I have a configuration object that I'm passing to the form. I'm trying to register the form with a 'prop' from my object, but it's not clear from the documentation how to pass that to the register function. How can I pass the prop value from my object to the register function?

If I pass prop I get the following error: `TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"prop" |` prop.${string}`'.`

Please see my code below.

```js
export interface Form {
  step_1: Controls;
}

export interface Controls {
  controls: Array<FormConfiguration>;
}

export interface FormConfiguration {
  question: number;
  label: string;
  prop: string;
  type: string;
  style: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  options?: Array<any>;
}

type Inputs = {
  prop;
};

const TextInput = ({
  label,
  prop,
  question,
  style,
  type,
}: FormConfiguration) => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<Inputs>();
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Inputs> = (data) => console.log(data);

  console.log(watch('prop')); // watch input value by passing the name of it

  return (
    /* "handleSubmit" will validate your inputs before invoking "onSubmit" */
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {/* register your input into the hook by invoking the "register" function */}
      <div>
        <label htmlFor={prop}>
          {question && `${question}.`} {label}
        </label>
        <input {...register(prop, { required: true })} />
        {errors.prop && <span>This field is required</span>}
        <input type="submit" />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default TextInput;

export const FORM: Form = {
  step_1: {
    controls: [
      {
        question: 75,
        label: 'Primary federal regulator',
        prop: 'Question_75', // trying to set this as the prop to the form
        style: '',
        type: 'dropdown',
        placeholder: 'Please select one',
        options: [
          {
            label: 'FCC',
            value: 'FCC',
          },
          {
            label: 'FDA',
            value: 'FDA',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        question: 76,
        label:
          'Filer name (Holding compnay, lead financial institution, or agency, if applicable)',
        prop: 'Question_76',
        style: '100%',
        type: 'text',
      },
      {
        question: 77,
        label: 'TIN',
        prop: 'Question_77',
        style: '50%',
        type: 'text',
      },
      ...
```

Comment: Is `prop` in type `FormConfiguration` a string?

Comment: Yes, please see the update.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Facing the same issue, thank you in advance and regards

Comment: @JavierGuzmán please see my answer below.

Comment: Thanks! I think I tried something similar and it did not work. I do not recall; I solved it by passing registration props to the child. i.e. registrationProp = register('whateverfield'), then within the child I would do {...registrationProp}

Comment: Interesting. Well, I'm glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this issue this is how I solved it.

```
<input {...register(`${prop}` as any, { required: false })} type="text" />
```